# Unable to switch back to default frame

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am working on the following scenario.

I click on an element in the main web page and it opens a dialog box. It is an iframe and i use `diver.switchTo().frame(1);` to access that frame. I am able to perform the required activites in that frame. Clicking on OK button in that frame will close it. Once the frame is closed i am not able to access any of the elements in the main page. I used the following to switch back to main page
`driver.switchTo().defaultContent()`and `driver.switchTo().frame(0)`. But none of them let me get back to the main page.

Since the frame gets closed i also tried without any switchTo() statements. But it didnt work either.

Please help me with other possible solutions for it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: please post relevant html

Answer (score 2):

You need to switch back to the original window (Java code)

```
String windowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle(); // save the original window handle

// handle the pop up

driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to switch back to the **Top-Level Browsing Context** your following code trial should have worked :

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

As an alternative you can also try :

```
driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
```

Sometimes it may happen that the driver looses the window focus and in that case you have to regain the focus on the browser by :

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.focus();");
```